# Async Await function

Tags: angular, typescript, asynchronous

```
async onSubmit() {
    await this.service.uploadFile(this.requestBody).subscribe((response: any) => {
      if (response.status === 'OK') {
        this.rowData2 = response.payload.contents;
        this.service.getPlan(this.form.value).subscribe((responsePlan: any) => {
          this.toastrService.show(
            'success',
            'MTI - AP Upload File',
            {
              status: 'success',
              duration: 5000,
            },
          );
          toastRef.close();
        });
          
      } else {
        this.toastrService.show(
          'error',
          'MTI - AP Upload File',
          {
            status: 'warning',
            duration: 5000,
          },
        );
        this.getLog(this.currentPage, this.paginationPageSize);
        toastRef.close();
      }
    });
    await this.service.getValidateLog(this.requestBody.filename);
    await this.service.getLogUpload(this.requestBody.filename);
  }
```

**
`My intention is run code asynchronous from Upload file and it show success to user and
getvalidatelog ,this function return which transaction are correct (Check by my backend )
and  getlogupload i mean show a detail to the table to show.
But this code didn't work How could i solve it ?

Comment: The `await` keyword only works with promises. Does `this.service.uploadFile(this.requestBody).subscribe` return a promise? I'm guessing it does not, since it looks more like an observable. And when you say the code "didn't work", can you be more specific? Did you see an error message? Did it execute things too soon?

Comment: Sometime await this.service.getLogUpload(this.requestBody.filename); run before 
await this.service.getValidateLog(this.requestBody.filename); and i will return object that contains success = 0 and error =0 because function Validate didn't complete.

Comment: `Sometime await this.service.getLogUpload(this.requestBody.filename); run before await this.service.getValidateLog(this.requestBody.filename);` Then please show the code for `this.service.getValidateLog`

Answer (score 1):

I suppose that `this.service.uploadFile` returns an `Observable` so it does not really make sense to use the `await` on `this.service.uploadFile().subscribe()`

`subscribe()` is a method that returns a `Subscription` and I don't think it makes sense to `await` a `Subscription`.

You have 2 options :

**Option 1 : map the Observable to a Promise**

`Promise` is *NOT* evil nor deprecated. When you are making an API call which has one response, it semantically makes sense to use a `Promise`

Use `firstValueFrom()` to map your `Observable` to a `Promise` and use `Promise` only

```js
import {firstValueFrom} from "rxjs";

async onSubmit() {
    const response = await firstValueFrom(this.service.uploadFile(this.requestBody));

    if (response.status === 'OK') {
        // [...] same code as yours
    } else {
        // [...] same code as yours
    }
    await this.service.getValidateLog(this.requestBody.filename);
    await this.service.getLogUpload(this.requestBody.filename);
}
```

**Note** : Due to lack of context, it is not clear about what happens in case of error. If the `uploadFile` function still returns a result but with `response.status = 'ERROR'`, this code will work. But if it throws an exception, you will have to surround the call with a try/catch, like this :

```js
async onSubmit() {
    try {
        const response = await firstValueFrom(this.service.uploadFile(this.requestBody));
        // [] Here, the code that you put in the "OK block" 
    } catch {
        // [] Here, the code that you put in the "ERROR block"
    }

    await this.service.getValidateLog(this.requestBody.filename);
    await this.service.getLogUpload(this.requestBody.filename);
}
```

**Option 2 : keep using an Observable**

In that case, remove the `await` keyword

Then the lines happening after the API response should be put in the callback that you pass to the `subscribe` function :

```js
onSubmit() {
    // Notice the async keyword in the callback !
    this.service.uploadFile(this.requestBody).subscribe(async(response: any) => {
        if (response.status === 'OK') {
          // [...] same code as yours
        } else {
          // [...] same code as yours
        }
        await this.service.getValidateLog(this.requestBody.filename);
        await this.service.getLogUpload(this.requestBody.filename);
    });
}
```

**Notes** :

- In that case, the `onSubmit` function itself does not need to be `async` anymore because there is no `await` in it anymore
- But notice that the callback passed to the `subscribe()` function becomes `async` : `.subscribe(async(response: any) => [...])`

Comment: Who is this person claiming Promises are evil and deprecated? Is it the village idiot?

Comment: @somethinghere it is a common belief since `Observable` exist and do "same as `Promise` and more". So it is always good to remember that one does not replace the other and that they are not intended for the same use case

Comment: Holy shit, `Observable` isn't even a standard. Do those people also think RXjs is a browser built-in or something? Tsssk.